# LinearSVC Feature Selection returns different coef_ in Python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, feature-selection

I'm using SelectFromModel with a LinearSVC on a training data set. The training and testing set had been already split and are saved in separate files. When I fit the LinearSVC on the training set I get a set of coef_[0] which I try to find the most important features. When I rerun the script i get different coef_[0] values even though it is on the same training data. Why is this the case?

See below for snip of code (maybe there's a bug I don't see):

```
fig = plt.figure()

#SelectFromModel
lsvc = LinearSVC(C=.01, penalty="l1", dual= False).fit(X_train, Y_train.values.ravel())
X_trainPro = SelectFromModel(lsvc,prefit=True)
sscores = lsvc.coef_[0]
print(sscores)
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

for i in range(len(sscores)):
    sscores[i] = np.abs(sscores[i])

sscores_sum = 0
for i in range(len(sscores)):
    sscores_sum = sscores_sum + sscores[i]

for i in range(len(sscores)):
    sscores[i] = sscores[i] / sscores_sum

stemp = sscores.copy()
total_weight = 0
feature_numbers = 0
while (total_weight <= .9):
    total_weight = total_weight + stemp.max()
    stemp[np.nonzero(stemp == stemp.max())[0][0]] = 0
    feature_numbers += 1

print(total_weight, feature_numbers)

stemp = sscores.copy()
sfeaturenames = np.array([])
orderScore = np.array([])
for i in range(len(sscores)):
    sfeaturenames = np.append(sfeaturenames, X_train.columns[np.nonzero(stemp == stemp.max())[0][0]])
    orderScore = np.append(orderScore, stemp.max())
    stemp[np.nonzero(stemp == stemp.max())[0][0]] = -1

lowscore = orderScore[feature_numbers]
smask1 = orderScore <= lowscore
smask2 = orderScore > lowscore
ax.bar(sfeaturenames[smask2],orderScore[smask2], align = "center", color = "green")
ax.bar(sfeaturenames[smask1],orderScore[smask1], align = "center", color = "blue")
ax.set_title("SelectFromModel")
ax.tick_params(labelrotation=90)

plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=2, bottom=.2, top= .85)
plt.show()

#selection of the top values to use
Top_Rank = np.array([])
scores = sscores

for i in range(feature_numbers):
    Top_item = scores.max()
    Top_item_loc = np.where(scores == np.max(scores))
    Top_Rank = np.append(Top_Rank,X_train.columns[Top_item_loc])
    scores[Top_item_loc] = 0
print(Top_Rank)
X_train = X_train[Top_Rank]
X_test = X_test[Top_Rank]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you set `dual=False`, you should be getting the same coefficients. What is your `sklearn` version?

Run this and check if you get the same output:

```
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification

X, y = make_classification(n_features=4, random_state=0)
for i in range(10):
    lsvc = LinearSVC(C=.01, penalty="l1", dual= False).fit(X, y)
    sscores = lsvc.coef_[0]
    print(sscores)
```

The output should be exactly the same.

```
[0.         0.         0.27073732 0.        ]
[0.         0.         0.27073732 0.        ]
[0.         0.         0.27073732 0.        ]
[0.         0.         0.27073732 0.        ]
[0.         0.         0.27073732 0.        ]
[0.         0.         0.27073732 0.        ]
[0.         0.         0.27073732 0.        ]
[0.         0.         0.27073732 0.        ]
[0.         0.         0.27073732 0.        ]
[0.         0.         0.27073732 0.        ]
```

Comment: Thanks for this. when I ran using the generated dataset X,Y I got the same answer as you. However I also looped 10 print statements from reading the data I'm using from an excel file I get different answers. I printed out the dataframe as well and the data is consistent and in the same order as well but the fit results in different coefficients.

Comment: "I also looped 10 print statements from reading the data I'm using from an excel file I get different answers". Do you mean that loading the data 10 times leads to different data? post the command that you are using please. this is weird. Can you add some data and the full code?

Comment: I see the issue. I adjustment of the C penalty parameter to a more granular level  which gave consistent results. If you change C to a more forgiving value such as 1 in your previous example you would get different results per iteration of the loop as well. Thanks for the brain storm, I'm relatively new to machine learning